# User, Cart and Products Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I would like to ask about the `User`, `Cart` and `Product` eloquent relationships. The `User` hasOne `Cart` and the `Cart` can have many `Product`.

```
class User {

    public function cart()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(App\Cart::class);
    }
}



class Cart {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Product::class);
    }
}



class Product {

    //
}
```

I have database table structured like:

`users`

```
- id
- email
- username
- password
```

`carts`

```
- id
- user_id
- product_id
- quantity
```

`products`

```
- id
- name
- price
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

`users` table is correct, but for `carts` table you shouldn't have `product_id` column because it's one to many relationship (cart can have multiple products), so your `carts` table should look like this:

- id
- user_id
- quantity

But looking further probably you don't want one to many relationship between cart and product, because probably products are common for all the users, so you need many to many relationship.

So you should define one extra table (pivot table):

`cart_product`

```
- cart_id
- product_id
```

and you should change `products` relationship in `Cart` model like so:

```
public function products() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class);
}
```

you should obviously create same reverse relationship for your `Product` model in case you need it.

Comment: I faced the same issue and also came up with this exact same method but the issue is, quantity on the cart table is unusable because of products M2M relationship, you need to update quantity for each product not the cart itself.

Comment: Unless you add an extra field to the cart_product table for quantity but when it's time to attach products, it becomes another issue. Still can't wrap my head around the proper way to do this without coding spaghetti

Answer (score 0):

You need Many-to-Many relationship. Create a pivot table having cart_id and product_id. This will be the foreign keys to cart and product table respectively. Then declare many to many eloquent relationship in both models.
When you are adding to cart you need to sync the cart to product id like this:

$cart->products()->sync($product->id,false);